# C#(Xamarin iOS) How to navigate from UITableView to other ViewController?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

What line of code should I put inside of RowSelected?

I already used this but no luck at all :/ .

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
    var vc = window.RootViewController;
    while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
    {
        vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
    }
    mainnearmisses myTarget = (UIViewController)vc.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("mnearm") as mainnearmisses;
    myTarget.email = locations[indexPath.Row].shopname + "";
    vc.PresentViewController(myTarget, true, null);
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? did it crash or nothing happened?

Comment: yeah it crashed. Any Idea sir?

Comment: what's the crash information

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at Smitten_iOS.LocationSource.RowSelected (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)

This was the error sir

Comment: Check your storyboard, the controller "mnearm" 's class is `mainnearmisses `or not.

Comment: set the breakpoint and try to debug, whether `myTarget` return null?

Comment: @YunCHEN there was nothing wrong on that part
mainnearmisses - Class
mnearm - Storyboard ID

Comment: @ColeXia I will try :)

Comment: I have just tested your codebase and it works , the only problem you can have is , storyboard identifier is misspelled .

Comment: @saketkumar thanks for that :D i tried it again and it works :D i dont know what happen :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions for you.

**1. Set the ViewController itself as parameter in the initializing constructor of the dataSource.**

*in ViewController*

```
this.TableView.Source = new TableSource(tableItems.ToArray(), this);
```

*in dataSource*

```
ViewController owner;
public TableSource (string[] items, ViewController owner)
{
    tableItems = items;
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

this can make your code easy to navigation to another VC.
just use this instead of looking for current vc on Windows .

```
this.owner.PresentViewController(myTarget, true, null);
```

**2. If your tableView  fills with the screen , you can change your ViewController to UITableViewController**.

since it inherits form IUITableViewDataSource , so it can handle the event(i.e. that method create the tableView) in its own class.

**3.As I mentioned above ,check if that viewController exists**

check the storyboard id and find the corresponding viewController in your project.

Comment: Thank You Mr.Cole Xia for your immediate and logical Response :)